# Dynamically Display Images in Array of Array

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

How do I iterate through the array images srcs for each object in the properties array below?

I have the following mock data:

```
let properties: Array<any> = [
    {
        id: 1,
        picture: ["https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/sfdc-demo/realty/house01.jpg", "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/sfdc-demo/realty/house02.jpg", "https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/sfdc-demo/realty/house03.jpg"]
}
```

I am able to display the Id from the property object, but how do I iterate through the array of image srcs to dynamically created slides with the image srcs?

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-card *ngIf="property.id">
            <ion-slides pager>

                    <ion-slide ng-repeat="pic in picture" style="background-color: green">
                      <img src="{{property.pic}}"/>
                    </ion-slide>

                  </ion-slides>
    </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Page Typescript:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {ActionSheetController, ActionSheet, NavController, NavParams, ToastController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {BrokerDetailPage} from '../broker-detail/broker-detail';
import {PropertyService} from '../../providers/property-service-mock';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-property-detail',
    templateUrl: 'property-detail.html'
})
export class PropertyDetailPage {

    property: any;

    constructor(public actionSheetCtrl: ActionSheetController, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public propertyService: PropertyService, public toastCtrl: ToastController) {
        this.property = this.navParams.data;
        propertyService.findById(this.property.id).then(
            property => this.property = property
        );
    }
}
```

Property Service TS:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import properties from './mock-properties';

@Injectable()
export class PropertyService {

  favoriteCounter: number = 0;
  favorites: Array<any> = [];

  findAll() {
    return Promise.resolve(properties);
  }

  findById(id) {
    return Promise.resolve(properties[id - 1]);
  }
 }
```

Where is my misunderstanding?

[Elements after Render (Rohit's suggested Solution)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PEnz.png)

Comment: Can you generate a snippet for your code?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow... I am using Visual Studio Code. How would I generate a snippet for all of these pages?

Comment: For such cases, you should use `https://stackblitz.com/` and add the minimum working code with your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
  <ion-content>
    <ion-card *ngIf="property.id">
      <ion-slides pager>

        <ion-slide *ngFor="let pic of property.picture" style="background-color: green">
          <img src="{{pic}}"/>
        </ion-slide>

      </ion-slides>
    </ion-card>
  </ion-content>
```

Comment: can you put a `console.log`  in `PropertyDetailPage` after the service call.

Comment: This worked! I accidentally attempted of the other answers and responded to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, I have iterated over `property.picture` and assigned the `pic` in image source.

```
        <ion-card *ngIf="property.id">
            <ion-slides pager>

                    <ion-slide ng-repeat="pic in property.picture" style="background-color: green">
                      <img src="{{pic}}"/>
                    </ion-slide>

                  </ion-slides>
    </ion-card>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quickly reply, but this did not display the images/slides either.

Comment: `<img src="{{pic}}"/>{{pic}}` add this in code and post me what you got

Comment: Thanks again, but the slides still do not display, however no errors are received either.

Comment: That was for debugging. Do you see `image` tags OR URLs after it?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the elements after they rendered, it seems the image source renders as unknown, and I'm only seeing once slide so it appears to we are not iterating through the array.

Comment: In regards to your question, I see neither. Upon placing {{pic}} into the page, I receive an illegal return statement error.

Comment: Can you try the updated code? replaced `src` with `ng-src`

Comment: I receive: polyfills.js:3 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ng-src' since it isn't a known property of 'img'. ("-repeat="pic in property.picture" style="background-color: green">
                            <img [ERROR ->]ng-src="{{pic}}"/>
                    </ion-slide>

Comment: for debug, add this code after the image tag, `<h1>{{pic}}</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
<ion-card *ngIf="property.id">
            <ion-slides pager>

                    <ion-slide ng-repeat="pic in property.picture" style="background-color: green">
                      <img [src]="pic"/>
                    </ion-slide>

                  </ion-slides>
    </ion-card>
```

Comment: Only one slide displayed and the image displayed as a broken link.